Docker Compose says "no container found for project"
With normal docker-compose it does try to start (but I have an issue in the build).
Why it does not work with docker compose?
 ls -la ./docker/local/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 4 jorgee jorgee 4096 abr 11 19:37 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 jorgee jorgee 4096 abr 11 16:54 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 jorgee jorgee 4096 abr 11 16:59 base_wordpress
drwxrwxr-x 4 jorgee jorgee 4096 abr 11 16:53 configs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jorgee jorgee  995 abr 11 19:37 docker-compose.yaml


docker compose --file ./docker/local/docker-compose.yaml -p nhco-be start
no container found for project "nhco-be": not found

version: '3.5'
services:
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - '.:/application'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=nhco
            - MYSQL_USER=nhco
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=nhco
        ports:
            - '8082:3306'

    webserver:
        image: 'nginx:alpine'
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - '../../wp-content:/application/wp-content'
            - './configs/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
        ports:
            - '8080:80'

    php-fpm:
        build: configs/php-fpm
        working_dir: /application
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=mysql
            - DB_NAME=nhco
            - DB_USER=nhco
            - DB_PASSWORD=nhco
        volumes:
            - '../../wp-content:/application/wp-content'
            - './configs/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini'



You almost never need a start command; it only works if you have a container in an unusual state of existing but stopped.  Do you mean docker compose ... up?

@DavidMaze yes I think that was the issue, thanks! I was becoming crazy, that explains why it suddenly started to work in another console

The docker compose is a newer project to migrate compose to Go with the rest of the docker project, it is the v2 branch of the docker/compose repo. The v1 branch of the docker/compose repo uses docker-compose command instead. There might be additional verifications in the build process of the more recent docker compose command which might explain why it refuses to start but with the docker-compose command it tries to start

This might be because the docker-compose command was replaced with docker compose as part of the transition to Docker Compose V2.
